# Query MongoDB from Terminal on Spring Boot app using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-shell

I have a Spring Boot app configured with default settings to use MongoDB.   In order for my Spring Boot app to work, I have to manually launch MongoDB from terminal so I thought I could do commands from the shell to see what I was doing in the app. The app starts and performs all of the CRUD functions specified.  When I launch mongo shell and do:
    use test

Test is the only db that list using

```
show collections
```

I then do:

```
db.test.find()
```

No records are listed, even though I get a dozen records back if I do a GET using Postman; therefore, the records are in mongoDB.  I don't know how to run queries on the instance of mongoDB that Spring Boot is using (if it is different than the one I manually launched).

Comment: Are u using the correct db.. By this you are using the test database and the test collection.. Is this as expected

Comment: I do "use test" before I run a command.  I do "show dbs" to list dbs and I see test as the database.  Did I miss something?

Comment: When you run show collections - Do you have a collection called test?

Answer (score -1):

I just got a chance to work on mongodb recently. Not sure if you found a solution to your question. It seems that when you do the following command, you should get the list of your databases:

```
> show collections
mydb
xxxdb
restaurants
system.indexes
```

Then you can run the .find() command base on your db name. You should be able to get the data output on your terminal.

```
> db.mydb.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("1234"), "address" : { "building" : "351", "coord"...........}
```

If you don't like to use a Terminal, here is another NOSQL handy tool that I use - "Robomongo" - http://robomongo.org  You can either run a query via the tool or just configure the UI for your data set.

Comment: This question is wrt sprintboot in particular, not mongo.